# Bidirectional bindings between Go and Dart

Tags: go, binding, dart, bidirectional

I am interested in writing server side application that utilizes both [Go](https://golang.org/) and [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/). Is there any way to bind these two languages directly?

I could not find any docs pertaining to this usecase.

Comment: I guess the closest is https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-vm/native-extensions

Comment: You can use any sort of RPC mechanism, rather than trying to glue these together through some intermediary C bindings.

Comment: Thanks guy's. Definitely want a native binding rather than RPC to avoid marshalling cost and api limitations of an rpc. I will probably use dart native-extensions with a cgo library with appropriate shims in go to make the development iteration time, and specifically go compilation time, more manageable.